# What is the difference of "__and__" and "__rand__" in class set?

Tags: python, python-3.x, set

I read the book "Fluent Python" by Luciano Ramalho. In the description of class `set`, he writes:

```
s & z   # s.__and__(z)   - intersection of s and z
z & s   # s.__rand__(z)   - inversion operator &
```

I can't understand. Why in the second case he doesn't write: `z.__and__(s)`. The author said: "intersection of s and z" != "inversion operator &".

Is `__and__` and `__rand__` equal for `set()` or not?

Comment: Assuming the author is specifically trying to explain about methods of `s`, not of `z`, the second example uses `s.__rand__` because `s` is on the **r**ight of the `&` operator.

Comment: If `z` does not have a `__and__` method or it returns `NotImplemented`, then and only then is `s.__rand__(z)` called (except it might not be called at all in this case, what with `set` being an internal type written in C).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I can't understand. Why in the second case he doesn't write:
>   `z.__rand__(s)`.

Because that's the very point of the reverse operators. They as well exist in the form of `__radd__`, `__rsub__` and so on.

If, when doing `a & b`, calling `a.__and__(b)` does not exist or returns `NotImplemented`, it tries (as a "last resort") to call `b.__rand__(a)`.

See [the relevant part of Python's documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__rand__) for details.

In your example, probably the class of `z` doesn't implement `__and__`, so it falls back to `s` which supplies `__rand__`.